# Cookies are not getting created in browser

Tags: session, tomcat, jakarta-ee, cookies

Now I am trying to set cookie from my J2EE application  for my jasper server on the localhost and getting the below response . I have passed domain name as .report.com but cookie is not created in browser . is there something wrong in below response to generate a cookie successfully in browser

Info : As localhost is not a valid domain name so I have changed localhost to jasper.report.com on system32/host file .

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  148
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 08 Oct 2014 14:36:43 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=89E39BF51000E23270CE40EAE425EBF4; Domain=.report.com; Expires=Wed, 08-Oct-2014 19:36:44 GMT; Path=/jasperserver/; HttpOnly
Vary    Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: how are you hitting your site? if you've got `http://localhost` in the address bar, then your browser will properly reject a report.com cookie because it's for a completely different domain.

Comment: I am accessing the site with report.jasper.com but problem is that  application is not setting cookie in the browser if i use domain like .google.com then it is creating cookie